# Tab Bar in View Based Application - XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios, uitabbar

How can I use Tab Bar in my View Based application in **second view** ?

EDIT :

(Suppose)My application contains four views. The navigation from firstView to secondView is simple , I want the Tab Bar on the secondView and connect rest of the two view with the Tab Bar.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by second view?

Comment: The Second View means I have 4 views in my application and From the FirstView to SecondView navigation is different and on the SecondView I need a tab bar for another views to add in.

Comment: Be warned that Apple thinks this is a bad idea. The View Controller Programming Guide (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1) says, "Although a navigation controller can be embedded inside a tab, the reverse is not true." Think about restructuring your app's navigation (or at least breaking the tab bar controller out into a modal view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the other hand I think this has been discussed here: [uitabbarcontroller / uitabbar in navigation based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082953/uitabbarcontroller-uitabbar-in-navigation-based-project)

Just take a look.

EDIT: If it is a navigation based app and you want your tabbar on the second view, just initialize the navigation controller and use pushViewController message to it and push the tabBarController onto the navigation stack.

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2,nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Place this wherever you wish to push this tabBarController from the first view, where the first view is a navigation controller based entity and viewController1,viewController2 etc are the view controllers from the tab bar items.

Comment: Thanks , but didn't worked for me. If you can provide any View Based application which has Tab Bar on any other view except main view tutorial or guidelines. Thanks