# TabBar in a View Based Application with a UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationbar, tabbar

I am making a View Based Application for iPhone and I am trying to make a UIView with a TabBar and a NavigationBar. The TabBar needs three buttons which should switch between three different UIViews. What is the proper way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate: Try refering previous post:

- [Navigation Based Application with TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599200/navigation-based-application-with-tabbar)
- [uitabbarcontroller / uitabbar in navigation based project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082953/uitabbarcontroller-uitabbar-in-navigation-based-project)